# How do I get this matrix?

Tags: math-mode, texmaker, matrices

[image]

How do I get the above matrix in LaTeX using Texmaker?

P.S. I need the matrix as an equation. I couldn't get using the general specifications of LaTeX.

Comment: What does this matrix even mean? Is it all cosines in the top row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    Q_{l} = \begin{bmatrix}
      I_{1} &                             &       &                           &       \\
            & \cos\varphi_{l}             & \dots & e^{jv_{l}}\sin\varphi_{l} &       \\
            & \vdots                      & I_{2} & \vdots                    &       \\
            & -e^{-jv_{l}}\sin\varphi_{l} & \dots & \cos\varphi_{l}           &       \\
            &                             &       &                           & I_{3} 
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]